# Grep query in C shell script not performing properly

Tags: scripting, csh

When I run the grep command on the command prompt, the output is correct. However, when I run it as part of a script, I only get partial output. Does anyone know what is wrong with this programme?

```
#!/bin/csh
set res = `grep -E "OPEN *(OUTPUT|INPUT|I-O|EXTEND)" ~/work/lst/TXT12UPD.lst`
echo $res
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wildcard is probably being processed by the shell calling awk rather than as part of the awk script.

try escaping the `*` with a `\` (i.e. `\*`)

Comment: I also tried set res = `grep -E 'OPEN \*(OUTPUT|INPUT|I-O|EXTEND)' ~/work/lst/TXT12UPD.lst`

Comment: You may need 2 backslashes - one for the shell running the command and one for the backticks

Comment: please stop guessing like this. Can you try on your end and let me know. IT is just wasting my time.

Comment: I notice your duplicate question uses single quotes instead of double - made your mind up yet? You have a problem with wildcards. You just need to figure it out!